# Based on given longitude and latitude locations of my friends, I want to invite them

Tags: ruby, geolocation

Let's say a "json" object is available with me at some file location, reading the file, evaluating the distance and inviting the friends is the task.

```
require 'json'
class GeoSearch
    attr_accessor :originalLatitude, :originalLongitude, :invitationMap
    def initialize
        @originalLatitude = 28.521134
        @originalLongitude = 77.206567
        @invitationMap = Hash.new
    end
    def degreesToRadians(degrees)
      return degrees * Math::PI / 180
    end

    def findDistance(lat1, long1, lat2, long2)
        earthRadiusKm = 6371

        deltaLat = degreesToRadians(lat2 - lat1)
        deltaLon = degreesToRadians(long2 - long1)

        lat1 = degreesToRadians(lat1)
        lat2 = degreesToRadians(lat2)

        arial = Math.sin(deltaLat/2) * Math.sin(deltaLat/2) + Math.sin(deltaLon/2) * Math.sin(deltaLon/2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2)

        distance = earthRadiusKm * (2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(arial), Math.sqrt(1-arial)))

        distance
    end

    def readJsonFile(fileName)
        file = File.read(fileName)
        jsonData = JSON.parse(file)
        jsonArray = jsonData["friends"]
        iteratorOnJson(jsonArray)
    end

    def iteratorOnJson(jsonArray)
        visitingFriendsIds = []
        jsonArray.each do |element|
            if(findDistance(@originalLatitude, @originalLongitude, element['latitude'], element['longitude']) <= 100)
                visitingFriendsIds << element['id']
                @invitationMap[element['id']] = element['name']
            end
        end
        visitingFriendsIds = sortElements(visitingFriendsIds, 0 ,visitingFriendsIds.length-1)
        sendInvitationtoFriends(visitingFriendsIds, jsonArray)
    end
    def sendInvitationtoFriends(visitingFriendsIds, jsonArray)
        visitingFriendsIds.each do |friendId|
            puts "id: " + friendId.to_s + "  name: " + @invitationMap[friendId]
        end
    end
    def sortElements(inputArray, low, high)
        if(low < high)
            partition = quickSort(inputArray, low, high)
            sortElements(inputArray, low, partition-1)
            sortElements(inputArray, partition+1, high)
        end
        inputArray
    end
    def quickSort(inputArray, low, high)
        pivotalPoint = inputArray[high]
        index = low
        for iterator in low..high do
            if(inputArray[iterator] <= pivotalPoint)
                swapElements(inputArray, iterator, index)
                index = index + 1
            end
        end
        index -1
    end
    def swapElements(inputArray, xIndex, yIndex)
        temp = inputArray[xIndex]
        inputArray[xIndex] = inputArray[yIndex]
        inputArray[yIndex] = temp
    end
end

GeoSearch.new.readJsonFile("/home/neha/Desktop/friends.json")#Add your fileName
```

If Json object look like:

```
# {
#   "friends": [
#   {
#   "id": "5",
#   "name": "Agueda",
#   "latitude": 28.521134,
#   "longitude": 78.206567
# },
#   {
#   "id": "2",
#   "name": "Hisako",
#   "latitude": 28.521134,
#   "longitude": 74.206567
# },
#   {
#   "id": "1",
#   "name": "Addie",
#   "latitude": 28.521134,
#   "longitude": 76.206567
# },
#   {
#   "id": "4",
#   "name": "Laure",
#   "latitude": 37.5758033375583,
#   "longitude": -122.012044535507
# },
#   {
#   "id": "3",
#   "name": "Maye",
#   "latitude": 41.77117,
#   "longitude": -87.888795
# }
# ]
# }
```

output the names and user ids of matching friends (within 100km), sorted by user id (ascending).

Is there any way to reduce the complexity of the methods which are written.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Haversine Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) to calculate distance and then add that distance to the hash of users. Sort that and select the ones within a given distance:

```
require "json"

friends=JSON.parse(DATA.read)['friends']

olat = 28.521134
olon = 77.206567

friends
     .map {|h| h['dist']=findDistance olat, olon, h["latitude"], h["longitude"]; h}
     .select {|h| h['dist']<100}
     .sort_by {|h| h['id']}
     .each {|h| puts "%s is %.2f kilometers away" % [h['name'], h['dist']]}

__END__
{
    "friends": [
    {
    "id": "5",
    "name": "Agueda",
    "latitude": 28.521134,
    "longitude": 78.206567
},
    {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Hisako",
    "latitude": 28.521134,
    "longitude": 74.206567
},
    {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Addie",
    "latitude": 28.521134,
    "longitude": 76.206567
},
    {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "Laure",
    "latitude": 37.5758033375583,
    "longitude": -122.012044535507
},
    {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Maye",
    "latitude": 41.77117,
    "longitude": -87.888795
}
]
}
```

Prints:

```
Addie is 97.70 kilometers away
Agueda is 97.70 kilometers away
```